# How to add more than one Outlet component react router dom V6?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router-dom

I'm using [react-router-dom](https://reactrouter.com/docs/en/v6) V6 and I would like to know if it was possible to add more than one Outlet component at the same time because I want to have one section to be replaceable and a footer

This is what I attempted

```
<Route path = "/" element={<AppToolBar/>} >
            <Route path = "/AboutMe" element={<AboutMe />}>
              <Route path="/AboutMe" element={<AboutMeIntro />} />
              <Route path="/AboutMe" element={<Footer />} />
            </Route>
</Route>
```

But it doesn't work since it doesn't identify a difference between each other so it will simply render twice the first one only instead of render first one and second one. Any ideas ? Maybe I'm ignoring something important

This is how it renders

[image]

**UPDATE**

Answer definitely did the trick

```
 <Route path = "/" element={<AppToolBar/>} >
    <Route path="/AboutMe" element={( <> <AboutMe /> <Footer /> </> )} >
      <Route path="/AboutMe" element={<AboutMeIntro />} />
    </Route>
  </Route>
```

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I'm understanding your question correctly, you want to render an about page with conditional children, and uncondtionally (*or conditionally but separate from the route/path*) a footer.

Assuming `AppToolBar` is rendering an `Outlet` for nested `"/"` children routes, continue the abstraction by having the `"/AboutMe"` route render an `Outlet` for its nested children routes. Render the `Footer` with `AboutMe` wrapper component.

```
<Route path="/" element={<AppToolBar/>} >
  <Route
    path="/AboutMe"
    element={(
      <>
        <AboutMe />
        <Footer />
      </>
    )}
  >
    <Route path="/AboutMe" element={<AboutMeIntro />} />
  </Route>
</Route>
```

If you are wanting to conditionally render the `Footer` then render conditionally.

Example:

```
<Route path="/" element={<AppToolBar/>} >
  <Route
    path="/AboutMe"
    element={(
      <>
        <AboutMe />
        {condition && <Footer />}
      </>
    )}
  >
    <Route path="/AboutMe" element={<AboutMeIntro />} />
  </Route>
</Route>
```

You could clean this up a bit by abstracting the JSX into a new wrapper component:

```
const AboutMeWrapper = () => (
  <>
    <AboutMe />
    {condition && <Footer />}
  </>
);
```

...

```
<Route path="/" element={<AppToolBar/>} >
  <Route path="/AboutMe" element={<AboutMeWrapper />} >
    <Route path="/AboutMe" element={<AboutMeIntro />} />
  </Route>
</Route>
```

Or abstract the footer *into* the `AboutMe` component.

Example:

```
const AboutMe = () => {
  // business logic

  return (
    <>
      <div /* AboutMe layout styling */ >
        ...
        <Outlet />
        ...
      </div>
      {condition && <Footer />}
    </>
  );
};
```

...

```
<Route path="/" element={<AppToolBar/>} >
  <Route path="/AboutMe" element={<AboutMe />} >
    <Route path="/AboutMe" element={<AboutMeIntro />} />
  </Route>
</Route>
```

Comment: Let me check this, but first for your first question, Yes the AppToolBar is Rendering the About Me and then the About me is rendering the middle component in this case the "Intro" But I have no idea where to render now the footer because I can't do two on the same one. Let me check your answer first to see what I can do. thank you I'll let you know in a minute if it worked or not.